# Apache proxy "404 page not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, apache2

I am trying to create a proxy on my Apache2 server, but it returns a **404 page not found**

Basically I am using it as an intermediary for the creation of an API, within my Linux server I make requests and it responds correctly, but already using the Proxy it responds with a **404 page not found**

I put an example of how I am creating the Proxy

```
<Location /consulta> 
ProxyPass "my:url.api" 
ProxyPassReverse "my:url.api"
</Location>
```